# Stack overflow issue in c++

Tags: c++, image, stack-overflow

I get stack over flow when I compile the following...

I am not sure why... I am trying to convert an image which is in planar intervened to row intervened and vice versa... It would be great to have some guidance....

Header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
extern "C"
{
#include "C:\Users\padmanab\Desktop\Marvin_To_UnsignedChar\multiplyImage\multiplyImage.h"
//#include "C:\Users\padmanab\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Marvin_To_UnsignedChar\multiplyImage\multiplyImage.h"
}

using namespace std;

class Image_Conversion
{
public:
    int color = 3;
    int width = 888;
    int height = 799;
    //Marvin::img<U16>& out;
    //Marvin::img<U16>& in;
    //unsigned char Convert_Marvin_To_MatlabImage();
    //void Convert_To_Marvin(unsigned char MatlabImage[3*799*888])
    unsigned char Convert_Marvin_To_MatlabImage(double Marvin_Image[3*888*799]);
    double Convert_To_MarvinImage(unsigned char Matlab_Image[3*888*799]);
    unsigned char Matlab_Image[3*799*888];
    double Marvin_Image;
};
```

cpp:

```
unsigned char Image_Conversion::Convert_Marvin_To_MatlabImage(double Marvin_Image[3*799*888])
{
    for (int h = 0; h < height; ++h)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; ++w)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < color; ++c)
            {
                Matlab_Image[c*height*width + w*height + h] = unsigned char(Marvin_Image[c*h*w]);
    return Matlab_Image[c*height*width + w*height + h];

            }
        }
    }



}

double Image_Conversion::Convert_To_MarvinImage(unsigned char Matlab_Image[3*799*888])
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < color; c++) 
            { 
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
                { 
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
                    { 
                        Marvin_Image = (double)Matlab_Image[c*height*width + x*height + y]; 
               return Marvin_Image;
                    } 
                } 
            }

}
```

Main function:

```
#include "Image_Conversion.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "C:\Users\padmanab\Desktop\Marvin_To_UnsignedChar\multiplyImage\multiplyImage.h"


int main()
{
    Image_Conversion Image_Conversion;
    return 0;
    double img[3 * 799 * 888];
    int parameter = 4;
    unsigned char Matlab_Image = Image_Conversion.Convert_Marvin_To_MatlabImage(img);
    const unsigned char Matlab_Const_Image = (const unsigned char)Matlab_Image;
    unsigned char Output_Image = multiplyImage(&Matlab_Const_Image, parameter, &Matlab_Image);
    std::cout << "Output =" << Output_Image;




}
```

Comment: FYI you shouldn't declare the array size in the function definitions. For example instead of `void foo(int[100])` you would just say `void foo(int[])`.

Comment: Hi, I changed that still I get the same error !

Comment: BTW, your function seems bizarre `return Matlab_Image[3*799*888];` is UB; a full loop to set `Marvin_Image` computed with the last element...

Comment: What is Convert_To_MarvinImage doing?

Comment: @Poldie The marvin image should convert the image into planar interleaved image(c[] r[] w[]) as rrrrr....gggggg......bbbbbb... and return the value...in a single matrix

Comment: @user3652437  It's just returning a double, even after the recent change you've made to the question.

Comment: Hi, I want to return all the value of Marvin_Image. What should I do.. Should I return the values in an array?

Answer (score 2):

Your stack is overflowing because you're storing too much on it. Each `Image_Conversion` object is some 2MB large (it contains the array), and the `double img` array you're storing in `main`'s stack frame is about 17MB.

That's apparently too big for the stack. You should store such big arrays on the heap, preferably using `std::vector`. For this, you'd change the class like this:

```
class Image_Conversion
{
public:
    int color = 3;
    int width = 888;
    int height = 799;

    Image_Conversion() : Matlab_Image(color * width * height) {}

    unsigned char Convert_Marvin_To_MatlabImage(double Marvin_Image[]);
    double Convert_To_MarvinImage(unsigned char Matlab_Image[]);
    std::vector<unsigned char> Matlab_Image;
    double Marvin_Image;
};
```

And `main` like this:

```
int main()
{
    Image_Conversion Image_Conversion;
    return 0;
    std::vector<double> img(3 * 799 * 888);
    int parameter = 4;
    unsigned char Matlab_Image = Image_Conversion.Convert_Marvin_To_MatlabImage(img.data());
    const unsigned char Matlab_Const_Image = (const unsigned char)Matlab_Image;
    unsigned char Output_Image = multiplyImage(&Matlab_Const_Image, parameter, &Matlab_Image);
    std::cout << "Output =" << Output_Image;
}
```

The conversion functions stay the same. But note that they probably aren't doing what they should. The first one returns an out-of-bounds value (it reaches past the array), and the second one has a `return` in the inner loop, so it will never actually loop. But these are separate issues.

Comment: 16MB, not 2MB — each `double` is (typically) 8 bytes.

Comment: Can you please explain me further how to store the array in heap... is it like `std::vector<double> Marvin_Image[3*799*888]` and then using it in the function definition like `unsigned char Convert_Marvin_To_MatlabImage(Marvin_Image);`

Comment: allocating on the heap means that you will use new and delete operators

Comment: @user3652437 Vectors are good for you and your sanity. You don't need any manual memory management. You should write `std::vector<double> Marvin_Image(3*799*888);` though, or you'll get an array of empty vectors.

Comment: @Wyzard But the member `Matlab_Image` is an array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: @user3652437 Expanded the answer.

Comment: @molbdnilo But I need to return the output as unsigned char and double, is it possible to cast the vector into these formats?

Comment: Hi inside the loop, I have to convert the Matlab_Image to double and the function should return as double, now it shows error as I cant type cast the Matlab_Image into double...

Comment: @Angew, sorry, I was looking at the array of doubles in `main()`.  That one's 16MB.

Comment: @user3652437 You're not doing any conversions even with arrays - both your "conversion" function are just returning the number `Matlab_Image[0]`. How do you expect to "cast" an array to a number?

Comment: @Wyzard And that's what the answer says :-)

Comment: @molbdnilo I dont get you, how do you say it returns just zero?? I have looped over the color, width and height to get the image values in the array ....

Comment: @user3652437 The only thing you do in your loops is to return the first element of the array (the one with index zero), because once you've said `return` on the first round where all indices are zero, the function returns and the loop is broken out of. I think you should get out your book and read some more about loops and functions and arrays.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you for your kind response, it would be great if you could give an example to store all elements and then return the variable which has all the values of the loops

Comment: "it would be great if you could give an example to store all elements and then return the variable which has all the values of the loops". Perhaps you could work out in pseudocode what you want to happen.

Comment: @Poldie Yep, but it seems way outside the scope of *this* question.

Comment: @Angew Yeah, I don't really want to see it, but it might make it clearer, in the questioners mind, what he actually wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

you allocate way too much on the stack (millions of arrays, each of which is 3 * 799 * 888 !). Try using the heap, with std::vector<> for instance.

EDIT:
Use the **new operator** to allocate an object on the heap:
auto v = new vector< vector< vector< double >>>

Do not forget to delete your allocations to avoid resources leaks, or better, **use smart pointers:**

auto v = std::unique_ptr(new vector< ... >) // use make_unique if available